# How to make a value scale with a probability?

Tags: probability, arithmetic

Say I have a 50/50 chance to win/lose, and I have another value which is strength which starts at 0 but rises up by 5 every win to a max of 95. And every 5 strength ups my odds to win up to 95/100. I know this is simple arithmetic but, for some reason I can't get an idea how to start it. I am basically just looking for the general formula or logic for this type of scaling

Comment: start what? whats the q?

Comment: How can your odds to win grow up to a value larger than $1$ (specifically $95/5$)?

Comment: @barakmanos My bad i meant 95/100

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: what are you asking for - the expected number of throws to reach the 95/5 win/lose ratio?

Comment: I'm looking for how I can calculate a growth between strength  which @JonMarkPerry starts at 0 and rises by 5 every win.  And ever 5 strength increases my odds of winning. 
Strength caps at 95
my chance to win will cap at 95% I am  trying to see how can I relate these so I can write an expression.

Comment: so a representative of the 'curve' called strength?

Comment: Yea, I believe so I'm not big on curves but I'm pretty sure that's what I'm looking for lol. Nevertheless it would still help me with my problem.

Comment: i would use a binary tree to get going, but i cant see where we are going

Comment: I don't know if I worded my question wrong but it feels as if we are overthinking, this I can include the instructions I don't know if  it will help.
 a. You will simulate a battle by using a random chance of 50/50.
        c . Your odds of winning a battle increases by every 5 strength points 
           for each battle you win.
        f. Strength cannot be below zero or above 95
 g. You will always have a 5% change of losing or higher

i assume this was a general math problem, and if not my bad for asking here and I can ask in stackoverflow for programming

Comment: sorry, haven't got a clue what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:
$$P(s) = \frac{50+\frac{45}{95}s}{100}$$
where $s$ is your strength and $P$ is the chance of winning. When $s=0$, the odds are 50-50, and as $s$ increases, so does $P$, up to $P(95) = 0.95$.

---

EDIT: I updated the formula to work for a maximum strength of $95$ instead of $45$. The formula can be simplified (starting by reducing $\frac{45}{95}$ to $\frac{9}{19}$), but I left it as written to show the relationship to $95$.

Comment: this is extremely close only thing is, I need strength to max out at 95 and not 45  not sure how to change that.

Comment: @Jude Oh, I see. I've updated the formula: all that was missing was to scale the value of $s$. Does this work now?

Comment: Yes this what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a simple computer program. Here is a JavaScript version of something similar.

```
    chanceToWin=0.5;
    strength=0;
    win=0;
    count=0;
    while (win<10) {
      count++;
      if (Math.random()<chanceToWin+strength) {
        win++;
        strength+=0.05;
        if (strength>0.45) strength=0.45;
      }
    }
    alert('You won 10 times in : '+count+' goes.');
```

Math.random() returns a random number from $[0,1)$.